# Oracle SQL Developer hides last character

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using the latest version of Oracle SQL Developer. I just couldn't figure why it is hiding last character please see picture.

Version 18.2.0.183
Build 183.1748

[image]

[error Pic-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0bOm.png)

Comment: Looks like GUI rendering glitch to me

Comment: How do i fix this please ?? tried re-install still same issue

Comment: If it is just a rendering problem why fix it? Leave it alone or switch to e.g. PL/SQL developer

Comment: Check your display, font settings in the code editor preferences

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to a different font family or size. This problem most likely affects just a particular font configuration.

This can be done by accessing *Preferences > Code Editor > Fonts* menu.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out!  This has been happening to me for the past several months - agony!  This may sound weird but here's what I did; I verified it again and it worked again.

Goto Preferences > Code Editor > Fonts
Turn off "Display Only Fixed Width Fonts
Then select Wide Latin font 
Select ok.
Then go back and select Verdana (may work to select a different one but at this point I'm not messing around anymore with it).
This was not necessarily my first choice however it was the only way I was able to select a font I could live with.

At the point of turning off the fixed width fonts and selecting something different, that didn't seem to fix the issue.  It was only until I selected the Wide Latin and then the Verdana that it seems to have fixed the issue.
good luck.